# Convert Array to Object for table Schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, react-typescript

What is the best way to convert:

```
["Foo", "Bar", "John"]
```

To:

```
{
Foo: { name: 'Foo', index: 0, type: 'String' },
Bar: { name: 'Bar', index: 1, type: 'String' },
John: { name: 'John', index: 2, type: 'String' },
}
```

I believe I need to utilize

```
array.map()
```

but am not sure how to structure my mapping function. Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do as follows

```
const array = ["Foo", "Bar", "John"];
Object.fromEntries(
   array
   .map((el, index) => {
     return [el, {name: el, index, type: el.constructor.name}]
   })
)
```

Here you can find an example snippet:

```js
const array = ["Foo", "Bar", "John"];
const result = Object.fromEntries(
   array
   .map((el, index) => {
     return [el, {name: el, index, type: el.constructor.name}]
   })
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @NicoloCode, do you need any additional explanations?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I may need the names without the "", including Foo, name, index, and type. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: It's just an object representation. It will work exactly the same as your example. If you copy the code and run it in browser console, you'll see the object properties without "" and singlequouted strings

Answer (score 1):

You can the function `Array.prototype.reduce` as follow.

```js
const source = ["Foo", "Bar", "John"],
  capitalize = string => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1),
  result = source.reduce((a, name, index) => ({...a, [name]: {name, index, type: capitalize(typeof name)}}), {});
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! super helpful. The result needs to be an object, although that wasn't clear in the question. I have updated the exact structure needed.

Comment: @NicoloCode you can use reduce for that. something like given that keynames are distinct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188099/how-to-reduce-array-of-objects-into-one-object

Comment: @NicoloCode you cannot have multiple repeated keys within an object.

Comment: @NicoloCode the names will be different from each other?

Comment: Yes, apologies as I cannot provide my original array as it's confidential. I have updated it to contain strings other than foo

Comment: @Ele And thank you that link is helpful

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid , so if you need the valid json like this

```
[{"name":"Foo","index":0,"type":"string"},{"name":"Foo","index":1,"type":"string"},{"name":"Foo","index":2,"type":"string"}]
```

you can use this code

```
var result=[];
arr.forEach( (element,i )=> {
  result.push( {name:element, index:i, type: typeof element});
 });
```

UPDATE

for your another json

```
var jarr=["Foo", "Bar", "John"]
```

you can use this code

```
var result = {};
jarr.forEach((element, i) => {
  result[element] = { name: element, index: i, type: typeof element };
});
```

result

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "name": "Foo",
    "index": 0,
    "type": "string"
  },
  "Bar": {
    "name": "Bar",
    "index": 1,
    "type": "string"
  },
  "John": {
    "name": "John",
    "index": 2,
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```